# If I am not using FastMM4 in full debug mode, is it any faster than the memory manager in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, delphi-xe2, fastmm

I use FastMM4, normally in full debug mode during development. If I turn off this mode should I arrange my app to go back to the Delphi (XE2) MM or is there a performance benefit in leaving FastMM4 linked all the time?

Comment: If you are having performance problems with heap allocation then you need a different allocator or to change your code to be less reliant on the allocator.

Comment: @David: I was including FastMM4 and leaving FullDebugMode enabled (slow) - even in deployed apps because its so nice. I'm weaning myself off it now :-)

Comment: you just need to use different options in debug and release

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi's memory manager (since <s>D2007, IIRC</s> D2006) *is* `FastMM4`, so you won't get any improvement in speed. The full `FastMM4` might be faster, because you get improvements and bug fixes by using it straight from the source.

Comment: FastMM is default since D2006 actually.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I said "IIRC"; I couldn't remember exactly, and 2007 is the oldest version I have installed here. (I have D7 in a VM  on another machine, but I can't get to it now, and I knew the old MM was still in that version.)